# Issue Posting Form Via jQuery - No Console Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to post a form via jQuery `.post()`, and it's not working as it should. I'm getting nothing from the console, and it's quite frustrating. Requesting help from an experienced JS user. Thanks a lot for all of your help!

**NOTE:** This form is constructed with CodeIgniter, and posts perfectly fine using its Form Helper and HTML conventional routes. The JS/jQuery method is what is not working properly.

**Form:**

```
    <form class="nice custom" id="create_form">

                    <h3>Create Event</h3>

                    <label for="intention"><strong>Intention:</strong></label>
                    <?php $intention_attributes='style="width: 100%; " class="show-on-phones" id="intention_dropdown"'; ?>
                    <?php echo form_dropdown('intention', $intention, 'Select Intention', $intention_attributes ); ?>
                    <div class="custom dropdown show-on-desktops" style="width: 100%; ">
                        <a href="#" class="current">Select Intention</a>
                        <a href="#" class="selector"></a>
                        <ul style="width: 100%; ">
                            <li>Select Intention</li>
                            <li>Option 1</li>
                            <li>Option 2</li>
                            <li>Option 3</li>
                            <li>Option 4</li>
                            <li>Option 5</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <label for="action"><strong>Action:</strong></label>
                    <?php echo form_input($action); ?>

                    <label for="date_of_event"><strong>Date:</strong></label>
                    <?php echo form_input($date_of_event); ?>

                    <label for="repeat_event"><strong>Repeat:</strong></label>
                    <?php $repeat_event_attributes='style="width: 100%; " class="show-on-phones" id="repeat_event_dropdown"'; ?>
                    <?php echo form_dropdown('repeat_event', $repeat_event, 'Never', $repeat_event_attributes); ?>
                    <div class="custom dropdown show-on-desktops" style="width: 100%; ">
                        <a href="#" class="current">Never</a>
                        <a href="#" class="selector"></a>
                        <ul style="width: 100%; ">
                            <li>Never</li>
                            <li>Every Day</li>
                            <li>Every Week</li>
                            <li>Every Two Weeks</li>
                            <li>Every Month</li>
                            <li>Every year</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <label for="end_repeat_event"><strong>End Repeat:</strong></label>
                    <?php echo form_input($end_repeat_event); ?>

                    <br />

                    <input style="width: 100%; " type="submit" name="submit" class="medium radius blue button" value="Create" id="create_button" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Submit Create Form
    $('#create_form').live('submit', function() {
        var data = $('#create_form').serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post(url, data, function() {
            document.location.reload();
        });
        return false;
    }); // End
```

Comment: What is "not working"?  If you watch network traffic (e.g. using IE9 Developer tools, etc) do you see a request sent across the wire?  What is the HTTP response code of that request?

Comment: Your `<form>` doesn't have an `action`. I can't remember how `this` resolves in your statement: `var url = $(this).attr('action');` Maybe adding the action explicitly will fix it.

Comment: Showing us the form as it exists after PHP is processed is more helpful.

Comment: The only change between this form and the CodeIgniter form is that `<form class="nice custom" id="create_form">` is `<?php echo form_open('user/planner/create', 'class="nice custom"', 'id="create_form"'); ?>`. CI form helper explained at the following: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html Using this method posts to my DB just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has no action value:

```
<form class="nice custom" id="create_form">
```

Even though you're attempting to get one:

```
var url = $(this).attr('action');
```

Also, avoid using `$.live` from here on out:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.
>
> — http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `.live()` and `.on()`. I'll implement that in from here on out. I'll remove the `.attr('action'); to see if that solves the issue. It was from an older version of the form.

Comment: I figured out the issue with your help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of your submit button to btnSubmit.  I've had issues in the past with naming the submit button submit.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Also, press the black dot button on the top of the console output tab (webkit browsers).  This will preserve log messages between page loads.